# Duplicate values on foreach loop php using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have form where I will iterate the list of motorbikes model in database with blank fields where user will input the chassis and engine number of models. The problem is when I submit the form the data was duplicated in database. Any ideas why?

views

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {

echo "<tr><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='order_id[]' id='id' value='$order_id'>             
      <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='model[]' id='model' value='$row->model'>$row->model</td>
      <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='color[]' id='color' value='$row->color'>$row->color</td>
      <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='quantity[]' id='quantity' value='1'>1</td>
      <input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='quantity_received[]' id='quantity_received' value='1'>
      <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='engine_no[]' id='engine_no' value='$engine_no' placeholder='Engine No'></td>
      <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='chassis_no[]' id='chassis_no' value='$chassis_no' placeholder='Chassis No'></td>
        </td>
      <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='promo[]' id='promo' value='$promo'></td>
      <input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='unit_cost[]' id='unit_cost' value='$unit_cost'>
    </tr>";

}
```

controllers

```
$this->load->model('purchase_order');

#Batch insert
$order_id                   = $this->input->post("order_id");
$model                      = $this->input->post("model");
$color                      = $this->input->post("color");
$quantity                   = $this->input->post("quantity");
$quantity_received          = $this->input->post("quantity_received");          
$engine_no                  = $this->input->post("engine_no");
$chassis_no                 = $this->input->post("chassis_no");         
$promo                      = $this->input->post("promo");
$remarks                    = $this->input->post("remarks");
$code                       = $this->input->post("code");
$receiving_date             = $this->input->post("receiving_date"); 
$purchase_order_no          = $this->input->post("purchase_order_no");  
$branch_code                = $this->input->post("branch_code");        
$unit_cost                  = $this->input->post("unit_cost");  
$supplier_name              = $this->input->post("supplier_name");  


foreach ( $quantity as $key=>$value )
{
    $insertOrders[] = array( 'id'=>null,
                           'purchase_order_no'=>$purchase_order_no,
                           'branch_code'=>$branch_code,
                           'order_id'=>$order_id[$key],
                           'model'=>$model[$key],
                           'color'=>$color[$key],
                           'quantity'=>$quantity[$key],
                           'quantity_received'=>$quantity_received[$key],
                           'engine_no'=>$engine_no[$key],
                           'chassis_no'=>$chassis_no[$key],
                           'promo'=>$promo[$key],
                           'remarks'=>$remarks,
                           'code'=>$code,
                           'receiving_date'=>$receiving_date,
                           'date_received'=>$receiving_date,
                           'invoiceDRNo'=>$invoiceDRNo,
                           'waybillNo'=>$waybillNo,
                           'unit_cost'=>$unit_cost[$key],
                           'supplier_name'=>$supplier_name,
                           'In'=>'IN'
                        );

}


# Batch update 
$result1 = $this->purchase_order->BatchInsertOrders1($insertOrders);
```

Model

```
public function BatchInsertOrders1($insertOrders){

    $this->db->insert_batch('purchase_order_qty', $insertOrders); 
    $result = array();
    $result['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
    $result['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    return $result;     
}
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: @NathanTuggy what do you mean?

Comment: Can you take out most of the various field update lines and so forth, reducing to the bare minimum? It also looks as though there's some code that's not formatted that way, and some output that's formatted as part of the code.

Comment: I think after first time insert you need update data there after. Or your getting duplicate data on time it self ?

Comment: @vijay4vijju im getting duplicate data when inserting.

Comment: Can you add code that how you are inserting ?